# keep running python script on website/ website holder

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, winscp

I'm holding the website by tool WinSCP, I have the py script can manually extract content from mysql to website

- py script

```
import mysql.connector
import webbrowser
import time


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="196.168.100.141",
  user="root",
  password="password123", 
  database="cloud_db",  
  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
                
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE FROM webpage")                       
                                         
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()


list_01 = []

for row in myresult:
  temp_val = row[0]
  list_01.append(temp_val)


print(list_01[5])    # Nordic

html_content = f"<html><h1>{list_01[5]} </h1></html>"


with open("test_0109_004.html","w") as html_file:
  html_file.write(html_content)
  
time.sleep(2)
webbrowser.open_new_tab("test_0109_004.html")
```

- (pic01) `(showing the picture that the content "Nordic85678" can be extract from mysql and show on website by pyscript)`
  [image]
- (pic03)
  [image]
- (pic05)
  [image]

---

- **Question: how to make py script keep execute in WinSCP tool**

so that I can just hold one html page, with same header and footer, and the get function in the middle, showing different content

> ex: same html page, showing A product
>
> `<same header>`
> `sql get "A product" , "A product details"`
> `<same footer>`

> ex: same html page, showing B product
>
> `<same header>`
> `sql get "B product" , "B product details"`
> `<same footer>`

the product name and product details are stored in mysql database

---

- **Question: how to make py script keep execute in WinSCP tool**

Comment: I have read found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239815/running-a-python-script-on-a-website-in-the-background) but the discussion haven't quite answered what I'm looking for. So  apologies for this question